# Javascript with blockchain development, address.trans returns [] when theres no transactions pend

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, blockchain

address.trans returns [] when theres no transactions pend
if(txs === []){
returns a transaction still

Any solutions? Basically registering a "depo" when I never depo'd to the generated wallet.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VbPT.png)

Comment: Click the hyperlink to see the image

Comment: `txs === []` is guaranteed to be `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be happening because an array is an object. And two objects even with the same value are not equal in JS because they have different reference.

You can see that below:

```js
let trans = [];
console.log(trans === []);
console.log([] === []);
console.log(trans.length === 0);
```

[`Array.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) can be one way to check it: